# Alternative to syntactically-heavy multiple lambda wrapper - how to avoid boilerplate code?

Tags: c++, lambda, proxy, refactoring, c++14

I find myself encapsulating multiple lambdas in a "proxy" object with a nicer interface in various parts of my code:

```
auto create_proxy()
{
    auto f_get_foo = [something]
    {
        return something_else();
    };

    auto f_set_bar = [something](auto x)
    {
        something_else(x);
    };

    auto f_render = [&window]
    {
        window.render();
    };

    return make_nice_proxy(   // .
        std::move(f_get_foo), // .
        std::move(f_set_bar), // .
        std::move(f_render));
}
```

I can use the proxy like this:

```
nice_proxy.get_foo();    // calls the stored `f_get_foo` lambda
nice_proxy.set_foo(15);  // calls the stored `f_set_foo` lambda      
nice_proxy.render();     // calls the stored `f_render` lambda
```

The problem is that writing and maintaining code for these proxies is very cumbersome and syntactically heavy:

```
template <             // .
    typename TFGetFoo, // .
    typename TFSetBar, // .
    typename TFRender  // .
    >
class nice_proxy_impl
{
// Hide the lambdas:
private:
    TFGetFoo _f_get_foo;
    TFSetBar _f_set_bar;
    TFRender _f_render;
    int _render_count = 0;

public:
    template <                // .
        typename TFwdFGetFoo, // .
        typename TFwdFSetBar, // .
        typename TFwdFRender  // .
        >
    nice_proxy_impl(             // .
        TFwdFGetFoo&& f_get_foo, // .
        TFwdFSetBar&& f_set_bar, // .
        TFwdFRender&& f_render)  // .
        : _f_get_foo(FWD(f_get_foo)),
          _f_set_bar(FWD(f_set_bar)),
          _f_render(FWD(f_render))
    {
    }

    // Expose the lambdas:
    void set_bar(int x)
    {
        some_side_effect();
        _f_set_bar(x);
    }

    auto get_foo() 
    { 
        return _f_get_foo(); 
    }

    void render() 
    {
        std::cout << "rendering...\n";
        _f_render();
        ++_render_count;
    }
};

template <typename... TFs>
auto make_nice_proxy(TFs&&... fs)
{
    return nice_proxy_impl<std::decay_t<TFs>...>(FWD(fs)...);
}
```

The purpose of the proxy class is to:

- Hide the lambdas from the user.
- Give the users a nice (and possibly richer) interface through which they can call the "hidden" lambdas.

I have multiple proxy classes in my codebase, which all privately store some perfectly-forwarded callable objects *(and expose them through `public` functions)*, and that are created using `make_xxx_proxy` functions.

While `make_xxx_proxy` is usually easy to implement and does not require much maintenance, every proxy class *(like `nice_proxy_impl`)* require one template parameter per function, one field per function and one perfect-forwarding constructor parameter.

With multiple proxy classes, even adding or removing a single "encapsulated function" becomes annoying fairly quickly. `get_foo` is repeated 5 times in `nice_proxy_impl` (in different forms).

**Is there a better and less syntactically-heavy solution for this "pattern"?**

I'm looking for a way of avoiding the constant lambda/function repetition, type decaying and perfect-forwarding, which is just boilerplate.

`make_xxx_proxy` functions also become hell to maintain if the passed arguments are not only functions, but also additional field. Parameter expansion cannot be used in that case, and every single function has to be decayed and forwarded.

Here's [a real example](http://pastie.org/10823976) of a `make_xxx_proxy`-like function. Proxies may contain additional data/methods, that use the "encapsulated lambdas" and additional fields in various ways. Here's [the corresponding proxy class](https://github.com/SuperV1234/ecst/blob/86906cb192df05807c6a8ef9e234b494a6caf74e/include%2Fecst%2Fcontext%2Fsystem%2Finstance%2Fexecute_data%2Fdata.hpp).

Comment: Can you provide an additional example of what you mean by `make_xxx_proxy`? Are all the proxies just a getter/setter pair?

Comment: ^^ as above, perhaps if we could see two examples of the nice proxy, there might be an opportunity to delve into template <template> territory.

Comment: @Barry: [here's a real example](http://pastie.org/10823976). Proxies may contain additional data/methods, that use the "encapsulated lambdas" and additional fields in various ways. Here's the [corresponding proxy class](https://github.com/SuperV1234/ecst/blob/86906cb192df05807c6a8ef9e234b494a6caf74e/include%2Fecst%2Fcontext%2Fsystem%2Finstance%2Fexecute_data%2Fdata.hpp).

Comment: Have you considered using `std::function`?  If not, do you have tested evidence why you shouldn't?  Is there a reason you are using lambdas and not, say, an interface and a class with methods?  Oh,and ick those macros.

Comment: @Yakk: I do not require any of the advanced `std::function` features *(type-erasure, move and copy support)* as I always am aware of the callable object's body when I am constructing the proxy. I am also using these proxies in performance-critical code - it is preferable to avoid any potential run-time overhead that `std::function` could introduce. I am using lambdas because the proxies are instantiated in multiple places with different captured variables and scopes - creating a separate class for every occurrence would be a lot harder to maintain and introduce significant boilerplate code.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo So, you didn't test, just assumed it would be costly.  Are you invoking the functions on a per-pixel per-frame basis?  (100s of millions of times per second)?  Are you creating 100s of thousands of `nice_proxy_impl`s?  Do the simple solution, *notice a problem*, then get fancy: don't get fancy because of a phantom performance issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I understand what you're actually asking, but you could reduce `make_nice_proxy` to just return a local class (thanks to C++14) with public members (so you can aggregate-initialize). This avoids having to rewrite most stuff:

```
template <class Getter, class Setter, class Render>
auto make_nice_proxy(Getter&& g, Setter&& s, Render&& r)
{
    struct Proxy {
        std::decay_t<Getter> _f_get_foo;
        std::decay_t<Setter> _f_set_bar;
        std::decay_t<Render> _f_render;
        int _render_count = 0;

        void set_bar(int x) {
            some_side_effect();
            _f_set_bar(x);
        }

        auto get_foo() {
            return _f_get_foo();
        }

        void render() {
            std::cout << "rendering...\n";
            _f_render();
            ++_render_count;
        }
    };

    return Proxy{std::forward<Getter>(g), std::forward<Setter>(s), std::forward<Render>(r)};
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this only works if `get_foo` and `set_foo` are `public` fields of `Proxy`, which kinda defeats the purpose of encapsulating the lambdas inside a proxy with a nicer *(and possibly richer)* interface. If I set the fields to `private`, I still have to write the huge constructor.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo Sure.  But that wasn't part of your question.  Most of that "proxy" class is relatively unrelated to the above problem anyhow?  Stuff the local `Proxy` in a private field of your proxy-wrapper if you want to hide it.

Comment: @Yakk: Apologies, I now understand that my question was not clear at all. I've edited it and hopefully it is easier to comprehend now. This is mainly a code refactoring question, as I am looking for a way to avoid repetition and boilerplate in these `xxx_proxy` classes and `make_xxx_proxy` functions that I am writing multiple times in one of my projects.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo I mean, still the same idea (edited). Outside of this, not sure what you're looking for - there's already a mechanism to write an arbitrarily rich interface for a class: manually.

Comment: @Barry I was thinking that the proxy *you* create is stored as a private member of the "public proxy".  The public proxy does `template<class ProxyFuncs> class PublicProxy { private: ProxyFuncs funcs; public: PublicProxy(ProxyFuncs&& fs):funcs(std::move(fs)) {} /*...*/ };` and lets the helper inject just the proxy funcs.  Naturally this means that the public proxy has to implement the interface it wants, as the OP wants fine control over that.  You could also mix inheritance and private ownership to split the default-public and secret proxies.

Comment: @Yakk I guess that does let the class be non-local.

Comment: @Barry it also splits all the extra junk the OP wants from the types of the arguments and the like.  The extra stuff the OP wants is in a template class with one or two parameters (private function struct and possibly public function struct), not 1 per function.  Each function name is named once in the function-local struct, and once in the factory function parameter list.

Comment: @Yakk: that sounds like a decent solution. I've tried it out and it does remove some of the boilerplate code. I'm likely to accept it if you post it as an answer.